# "Edit" command in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-10g

In Toad, you can use

```
edit tablename where ...
```

and then simply edit the data in DB. Is there any equivalent in Oracle SQL developer?

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can double click on the table name and and then edit it

[image]

Note: you should *also* be able to edit the data from the data grid shown in the SQL Worksheet but I haven't confirmed that

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + Mouse hover over the table or view name, that will open up Table Editor and you can edit the field values.